# Unclosed File Warning in Python

Tags: python-3.x, apt

I've written the following code:

```
class LazyPackageLoader:
    def __init__(self, package_names):
        self.package_names = package_names

    def install_packages(self):
        try:
            cache = apt.cache.Cache()
            cache.update()
            cache.open()

            for package in self.package_names:
                pkg = cache[package]
                pkg.mark_install()

            cache.commit()

        except Exception as e:
            print (str(e))

        finally:
            cache.close()

    def show_all_packages(self):
        pkgs = list()
        cache = apt.Cache()

        for package in cache:
            if cache[package.name].is_installed:
                pkgs.append(package.name)

        cache.close()
        return pkgs
```

I call it like this:

```
class TestLazyPackageLoader(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_installed_package(self):
        packagelist = list()
        packagelist.append("ethtool")

        lpl = LazyPackageLoader(packagelist)
        lpl.install_packages()

        packages = lpl.show_all_packages()
        if "ethtool" in packages:
            self.assertEqual(True, True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The code is working as expected, however I get the following warnings:

> ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name=44 mode='w'
>   encoding='UTF-8'>   cache.commit
>
> ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name=43 mode='r'
>   encoding='UTF-8'>   cache.commit()

I guess the warning is plain enough: There exists an unopened file, which gets closed by Python eventually.

I've been reading up on this and think I should wrap the code within a 'with' statement, which is easy enough for reading a simple text file, but I can't figure it out how to do it with this library. I think the quintessential call here is `cache.close`, which I thought would get definitely executed when *`finally`* is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick lookaround in the [python-apt repo](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/python-apt/blob/master/apt/cache.py) showed that the `apt.cache.Cache()` class implement the two methods needed by the `with` keyword, i.e. `__enter__()` and `__exit__()`.

Which means that you just need to do:

```
with apt.cache.Cache() as c:
   # ... do your things with c ...

# here, c is closed
```

An example from your code:

```
def show_all_packages(self):
    with apt.cache.Cache() as cache:
        return [package.name for package in cache if cache[package.name].is_installed]
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer on the grounds that it answered my question about wrapping the statement in a `with` block.